# Updating JSON file using Collections Google/gson library

Tags: java, json, collections

I have a list of ObjectA: `List<ObjectA> listA;` .

I am trying to print all listA into JSON file, then I use in my function that do it.
`Files.write(Paths.get(filename), Collections.singleton(json.toJson(listA)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

And this is works fine. (Just to make it clear - the type of json is Gson (`Gson json = new Gson()`)

But, I am trying to add the following line in the JSON file before closing json: `}`. i.e 
I am trying to add the following line: `"SomeString: " + someIntValue/AtomicInteger value`
for example: `sum: 8` at the end of the JSON file before as said `}`.

How can I do it without print print each object in listA with iterator?
is it possible to make it easy as I do it for listA with one line? 
and somehow edit this, for example add listA before opening `[`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to wrap your List in an object and let gson do the hard work.

```
class ListAWithStatistics {
    List<ObjectA> listA;
    int someString;
}
```

This wrapper class would also help you to easily deserialize the produced json.